# SAS: lookup data inside a function/subroutine / return an array

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Suppose I like to do something like the following (with exemplary variable names for better readability):

1. take a parameter `InParameter` and match it to the variable `MyVar1` in a dataset `MyData`
2. return all values for the variable `MyVar2` for the filtered observations
3. from a subroutine/function
4. that i can use inside proc sql/datastep

This is what I got so far (clearly not working):

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.funcs.MyFunction;
    function MyFunction(InParameter $);
        array MyArray ... ; /* Here: Create an array with something like SELECT MyVar2 FROM MyData WHERE MyVar1 = Inparameter  */
        return(MyArray{});
    endsub;
    ;
quit;

options cmplib=work.funcs;

data MyOutput;
    set Somedata;
    if MyVar2 in MyFunction("H20") then output;
run;
```

**In short:**

- can data in datasets be accessed from inside a function/subroutine?
- can a function/subroutine return an array?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: An array in SAS is a fancy variable list.  A function returns a value.  A CALL routine can alter the values of one or more existing variables.

Comment: ok, so i would take a `subroutine` over a `function`, since an array is always considered several variables?

Comment: I think you will need to wrap your function in a macro so that you could generate valid SAS syntax for your `in` operator usage. In which case do you still need to make the function?

Comment: A function does not know its operating context. Thus if your idea is that *"the function should know that it is being called from a DATA step and I want the function to know the variables available in the active SET or PDV"* that is a dead-end idea.

Comment: @Richard the idea was to return some values out of another, hard coded dataset (i reckon that would not be what you call the "operating context") in a fashion that allows the return-value to be used in a datastep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We created a utility macro called `%ds2list()` that will perform your desired process.  It doesn't use an array statement but it achieves the same result.

The macro simply returns values from a dataset in a list format.  Here's an example of calling it:

```
%put %ds2list(iDs=sashelp.class, iField=name, iQuote=1);
```

This would return:

```
'Alfred','Alice','Barbara','Carol','Henry','James','Jane','Janet','Jeffrey','John','Joyce','Judy','Louise','Mary','Philip','Robert','Ronald','Thomas','William'
```

The default behavior for `%ds2list()` is to comma separate the returned values but it is very flexible.  You can change the delimiter to a value of your choice (or no delimiter), you can turn the quotes on or off, or change them from single to double quotes, and you can provide any dataset options you would normally use on a `set` statement such as a `where=()` statement.

Additionally because the macro is pure macro code you can use this literally anywhere in SAS.  In any proc/data/macro you like.  We use it extensively for calls to ODBC passthrough when we have a large list of IDs we want to be returned.

Here's an example of how you could use it.  First create a table that will contain values to compare against the list values:

```
data keep;
  input name $;
  datalines;
Alfred
Carol
Janet
run;
```

Iterate over the values we want to check against the list:

```
data want;
  set keep;
  if name in (%ds2list(iDs=sashelp.class, iField=name, iQuote=1, iDsOptions=where=(sex='F'))) then do;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Returns:

```
Obs    name
===    =====
 1     Carol
 2     Janet
```

You can see Alfred was excluded from the result because he was filtered out by the `where=()` clause.

Here is the macro, I suggest putting it in your macro autocall library:

```
/***************************************************************************
**  PROGRAM: MACRO.DS2LIST.SAS
**
**  UTILITY PROGRAM THAT DETECTS RETURNS A LIST OF FIELD VALUES FROM A 
**  DATASET IN DELIMITED FORMAT.
**
**  PARAMETERS:
**  iDs       : THE LIBNAME.DATASET NAME THAT YOU WANT TO CHECK.
**  iField    : THE FIELD THAT CONTAINS THE VALUES YOU WANT RETURNED IN A 
**              DELIMITED FORMAT.
**  iDelimiter: DEFAULT IS A COMMA. THE DELIMITER TO USE FOR THE RETURNED LIST.
**  iDsOptions: ANY STANDARD DATASET OPTIONS THAT YOU WOULD LIKE TO APPLY SUCH 
**              AS A WHERE STATEMENT.
**  iQuote    : (0=NO,1=YES). DEFAULT=0/NO. DETERMINES WHETHER THE RETURNED 
**              LIST IS QUOTED OR NOT.
**  iQuoteChar: (SINGLE,DOUBLE) DEFAULT=SINGLE. SPECIFIES WHETHER SINGLE
**              OR DOUBLE QUOTES ARE USED WHEN QUOTING THE RETURNED LIST
**
*****************************************************************************/

%macro ds2list(iDs=, iField=, iDsOptions=, iDelimiter=%str(,), iQuote=0, iQuoteChar=single);
  %local dsid pos rc result cnt quotechar value;

  %let result=;
  %let cnt=0;

  %if &iQuote %then %do;
    %if "%upcase(&iQuoteChar)" eq "DOUBLE" %then %do;
      %let quotechar = %nrstr(%");
    %end;
    %else %if "%upcase(&iQuoteChar)" eq "SINGLE" %then %do;
      %let quotechar = %nrstr(%');
    %end;
    %else %do;
      %let quotechar = %nrstr(%");
      %put WARNING: MACRO.DS2LIST.SAS: PARAMETER IQUOTECHAR INCORRECT. DEFAULTED TO DOUBLE;
    %end;
  %end;
  %else %do;
    %let quotechar = ;
  %end;

  /*
  ** ENSURE ALL THE REQUIRED PARAMETERS WERE PASSED IN.
  */
  %if "&iDs" ne "" and "&iField" ne "" %then %do;

    %let dsid=%sysfunc(open(&iDs(&iDsOptions),i));
    %if &dsid %then %do;

      %let pos=%sysfunc(varnum(&dsid,&iField));
      %if &pos %then %do;

        %let rc=%sysfunc(fetch(&dsid));
        %do %while (&rc eq 0);

          %if "%sysfunc(vartype(&dsid,&pos))" = "C" %then %do;
            %let value = %qsysfunc(getvarc(&dsid,&pos));
            %if "%trim(&value)" ne "" %then %do;
              %let value = %qtrim(&value);
            %end;
          %end;
          %else %do;
            %let value = %sysfunc(getvarn(&dsid,&pos));
          %end;

          /* WHITESPACE/CARRIAGE RETURNS REMOVED IN THE BELOW LINE */
          /* TO ENSURE NO WHITESPACE IS RETURNED IN THE OUTPUT.    */
          %if &cnt ne 0 %then %do;%unquote(&iDelimiter)%end;%unquote(&quotechar&value&quotechar.)

          %let cnt = %eval(&cnt + 1);
          %let rc  = %sysfunc(fetch(&dsid));
        %end;

        %if &rc ne -1 %then %do;
          %put WARNING: MACRO.DS2LIST.SAS: %sysfunc(sysmsg());
        %end;

      %end;
      %else %do;
        %put ERROR: MACRO.DS2LIST.SAS: FIELD &iField NOT FOUND IN DATASET %upcase(&iDs).;
      %end;
    %end;
    %else %do;
      %put ERROR: MACRO.DS2LIST.SAS: DATASET %upcase(&iDs) COULD NOT BE OPENED.;
    %end;

    %let rc=%sysfunc(close(&dsid));

  %end;
  %else %do;
    %put ERROR: MACRO.DS2LIST.SAS: YOU MUST SPECIFY BOTH THE IDS AND IFIELD PARAMETERS TO CALL THIS MACRO.;
  %end;

%mend;
```

Comment: Great piece of code that definetly does do what I need it to do!

Comment: Sadly, the forum doesnt allow me to mark both your excellent and similar codes as answers. While I end up using a variantion of this one, I reckon that other users might have an easier time playing around with Tom's a less extensive approach.

Comment: @MartinDreher Yeah - it's always nice to have options.  The only real differences between mine and Tom's are that mine does some error checking, and parameter checking, and print's out debugging information.  Mine also allows a choice of delimiters.  Otherwise they're basically the same.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that a function would work with the `IN` operator.  You might need to wrap the function call with a macro to generate the proper syntax. In which case why not just make a macro to begin with?

Here is generic macro to extract the values from a variable in a dataset.

```
%macro varlist
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------
Generate list of values from dataset
----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
(dataset     /* Input dataset */
,variable    /* Variable Name */
,quote=1     /* Add quotes around values? 1=Single 2=Double */
,comma=1     /* Add comma between values? */
,paren=1     /* Add parentheses around results? */
);
%local did sep &variable ;
%if &paren=1 %then (;
%let did=%sysfunc(open(&dataset));
%syscall set(did);
%do %while(0=%sysfunc(fetch(&did)));
  %let &variable=%qsysfunc(trim(%superq(&variable)));
  %if &quote=1 %then &sep.%sysfunc(quote(&&&variable,%str(%')));
  %else %if &quote=2 %then &sep.%sysfunc(quote(&&&variable));
  %else &sep.&&&variable;
  %if &comma=1 %then %let sep=,;
%end;
%let did=%sysfunc(close(&did));
%if &paren=1 %then );
%mend varlist;
```

Example calls:

```
%put %varlist(sashelp.class,name);
%put %varlist(sashelp.class(where=(sex='M')),age,quote=0,comma=0);
```

So in your case you might use it like this:

```
data MyOutput;
  set Somedata;
  where MyVar2 in %varlist(Mydata(where=(MyVar1="H20")),MyVar2) ;
run;
```

Comment: Tom. This is bloody brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off with a macro.

```
%macro subset(inParameter, indata, outdata);

proc sql noprint;
create table &outdata as
select * from &indata
   where myVar2 in (select distinct myVar2 from myData where myVar1 = "&inParameter);
quit;
%mend;

%subst(H20,Somedata,MyOutput);
```

Comment: Not quite what I am looking for, but this is likely bc my question was poorly phrased.
This replicates the result of my last datastep. However, my problem is the creation of this particular dataset with varying filters. I could do that with, say, a `call execute(proc sql)` inside my datastep). I want to **provide a readable way to filter in the described way in any data step**, regardless of any other operations I perform.