# Solution to macro-variable length exceeding maximum allowed error

Tags: sas

Had a SAS Program that has been working for a while but I am now facing macro-variables length issues. I will try to resume what the program does:

```
/* Buffing implicit macro-variable: */
proc sql noprint;
    select quote(trim(col))  into :implicit separated by " "
    from have
    where col contains "%";

/* Buffing valid_from macro-variable, format 16. to bypass 
   scientific notation */
proc sql noprint;
    select VALID_FROM format=16. into :valid_from separated by " "
    from have
    where col contains "%";

/* Buffing valid_to macro-variable, format 16. to bypass 
   scientific notation */
proc sql noprint;
    select VALID_TO format=16. into :valid_to separated by " "
    from have
    where col contains "%";
quit;

/* If &implicit. is not empty, then retrieve implicit col */
%if %sysevalf(%quote(&implicit.)=,boolean) = 0 %then %do;
    /* Loop on each col */
    %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&implicit.," "));
        /* Initializing the current expression, valid_from, valid_to */
        %let current_expression = %scan(&implicit.,&i.," ");
        %let current_valid_from = %scan(&valid_from.,&i.," ");
        %let current_valid_to = %scan(&valid_to.,&i.," ");

        %let _timer_start = %sysfunc(datetime());
        
        /* Retrieve current implicit col */
        /* And the corresponding valid_from and valid_to */
        data to_append;
            set BIG_TABLE
            (where=(upcase(col) like "&current_expression."));
            VALID_FROM = &current_valid_from.;
            VALID_TO = &current_valid_to.;
        run;
        
        /* End timer */
        data _null_;
            dur = datetime() - &_timer_start;
            put '<< Retrieved implicit col:' 
                "&current_expression." '. Time:' dur time13.2 ' >>';
        run;

    /* Append to the corresponding corporate_store */
    proc append base=want data=to_append;run;
    
    /* Delete append table */
    proc datasets lib=work nolist;delete to_append;quit;run;
    %end; /* End loop on each col */
%end;

/* If &implicit. macro-variable is empty, then there are no implicit col to retrieve */
%else %do;
    %put << No implicit col to retrieve... >>;
%end;
```

For information, the `&implicit.` macro-variable looks like this: `A[100][%][10] B[10][%][%]` and the purpose is to get from `BIG_TABLE` all rows that follows the like condition so: `A[100][10][10]`, `A[100][20][10]`, and so on...

However, today the length of the `&implicit.` macro-variable exceeded the maximum length (65534) and I got the following error message:

```
ERROR: The length of the value of the macro variable IMPLICIT (65540) exceeds the maximum length (65534). The value has been 
       truncated to 65534 characters.
```

I came across @Tom's solution on [Create several SAS macro variable lists from single dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52772490/create-several-sas-macro-variable-lists-from-single-dataset) and decided to reproduce it:

```
%let n_per_list=100;
/* Buffing &implicit. */
data _null_;
    length idlist $32000;
    length macrolist $1000;
    retain macrolist;

    do i=1 to &n_per_list. until (eof);
        set have(where=(col contains "%")) end=eof;
        idlist=catx(' ',idlist,quote(trim(col)));
    end;

    listno+1;
    call symputx(cats('implicit',listno),idlist);
    macrolist=catx(' ',macrolist,cats('&','implicit',listno));
    call symputx('implicit',macrolist);
run;

/* Buffing valid_from macro-variable, format 16. to bypass 
   scientific notation */
data _null_;
    length idlist $32000;
    length macrolist $1000;
    retain macrolist;

    do i=1 to &n_per_list. until (eof);
        set have(where=(col contains "%")) end=eof;
        format valid_from 16.;
        idlist=catx(' ',idlist,valid_from);
    end;

    listno+1;
    call symputx(cats('valid_from',listno),idlist);
    macrolist=catx(' ',macrolist,cats('&','valid_from',listno));
    call symputx('valid_from',macrolist);
run;

/* Buffing valid_to macro-variable, format 16. to bypass 
   scientific notation */
data _null_;
    length idlist $32000;
    length macrolist $1000;
    retain macrolist;

    do i=1 to &n_per_list. until (eof);
        set have(where=(col contains "%")) end=eof;
        format valid_to 16.;
        idlist=catx(' ',idlist,valid_to);
    end;

    listno+1;
    call symputx(cats('valid_to',listno),idlist);
    macrolist=catx(' ',macrolist,cats('&','valid_to',listno));
    call symputx('valid_to',macrolist);
run;
```

But I am getting the following error because it still truncates my macro to the maximum allowed length:

`ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required. The condition was:`

Hence I would like to know if there is a trick to bypass this error or if there is a more efficient way to do this. I was thinking of lookup using hash tables but I am not sure it handle the like condition.

Note that `have` is rather small (approx. 3000 rows) and `BIG_TABLE` around 80M rows.

Comment: What are you planning to do with the string that is over 64K bytes long?  The example usage you linked was just using the string as part of the generated SAS code. Note that none of the generated code contained any string literals that were larger than the SAS limit of 32K bytes of string literals.

Comment: Can you explain what SAS code you are trying to generate from data by using your original program?  I think it looks like you are just trying convert text to from/to numbers.  Why not just define two INFORMATS instead of using macro variables?

Comment: @Tom  Basically I have a data `have` that has a column `col` populated with like condition to be used in the SAS code (e.g. `A[100][%][10]`). I am trying to retrieve all rows that follows this like condition (e.g. `col` in `BIG_TABLE` like `A[100][10][10]` or `A[100][20][10]`)

Comment: What is VALID_FROM and VALID_TO?

Comment: I think the string literal cause problem in the following SAS lines: `%if %sysevalf(%quote(&implicit.)=,boolean) = 0 %then %do;` and `%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&implicit.," "));` because if I try outside of the macro, it gives me `ERROR: The text expression length (65559) exceeds maximum length (65534). The text expression has been truncated to 65534 characters.`

Comment: You cannot re-parse the generated string. But there is no need to generate the large string.

Comment: @Tom VALID_FROM and VALID_TO are dates associated to each `col` in `have`. So for each row of `have`, there is an associated `valid_from` and `valid_to`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to eliminate the need to make such a large macro variable is to just keep the data in the dataset.

It looks like you are trying to do something like this for each observation in the HAVE dataset.

```
%macro to_append(expression,valid_from,valid_to);

data to_append;
  set BIG_TABLE;
  where upcase(col) like &expression ;
  VALID_FROM = &valid_from.;
  VALID_TO = &valid_to.;
run;

%put << Retrieved implicit col: &expression
 %sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(datetime())-&_timer_start,time13.2)) >> ; 

proc append base=want data=to_append force;
run;

%mend to_append;
```

So just use the dataset to generate one call to the macro for each observation. Perhaps by using CALL EXECUTE().

```
data _null_;
  set have;
  call execute(cats
    ('%nrstr(%to_append)'
    ,'(',quote(trim(col),"'")
    ,',',valid_from
    ,',',valid_to
    ,')'
    )
  );
run;
```

Or just write the code to a file and %include it.

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
   set have;
   put '%to_append(' "'" col +(-1) "'," valid_from ',' valid_to ')';
run;
%include code / source2;
```

**Note**: Including the single quotes around the value of `COL` in the macro call will prevent the macro processor from trying to interpret the `%` characters.

There is also the "macro array" approach.  Personally I don't find that method worth the effort as just using the data directly is easier.  The idea is to create N separate macro variables rather than concatenating N values into one macro variable.

```
proc sql noprint;
  select quote(trim(col),"'"), valid_from, valid_to
    into :expression1-,:valid_from1-,:valid_to1-
    from have
  ;
%let n=&sqlobs;
quit;

%do i=1 %to &n ;

data to_append;
  set BIG_TABLE;
  where upcase(col) like &&expression&i ;
  VALID_FROM = &&valid_from&i;
  VALID_TO = &&valid_to&i;
run;
...
%end ;
```

Comment: I'd do either of these, or use `proc sql; select ... into :callstr from ... ; quit; &callstr;` even.  Anything but parsing strings in the macro language!

Comment: @Joe `proc sql; select ... into :callstr from ... ; quit; &callstr;` is what I was using

Comment: @Kermit No, it's not - you're creating a big macro string and then parsing it.  I'm suggesting doing what Tom says, and putting those _calls_ into the string.  It might still have a limit, though, depending on other details, but then you could move the selection of expression inside the macro.